# What does it mean "Active today"?

Tags: support, questions, last-activity

Today is the 22nd of February. I have edited a post yesterday and posted a bounty. There has been no other activity as far as the timeline is concerned. Yet, under the title it says

> Active today

[image]

What does it mean that a post is active today? Is it counted in a different timezone than UTC? Is it the past 24 hours?

The post in question: [Why does multi_query does not work when I use transactions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40088056/why-does-multi-query-does-not-work-when-i-use-transactions)

Comment: Now that 24 hours have passed it shows as Active Yesterday. I assume it means that it counts 24 hour period, not UTC day.

Answer (score 3):

You posted a bounty 23 hours ago. When you set a bounty, "Active" is bumped.

Comment: I know, but if it was 23 hours ago it still happened yesterday, right?

Comment: Are you saying that an active bounty will keep bumping the question until it ends?

Comment: Which is exactly my question. What does it mean? A UTC day? My local day? Last 24 hours?

Comment: "Day" on SO means different things depending on the situation.  In most cases it refers to a UTC day but in terms of the "active" label, it means "in the last 24 hours"